# My php logout function doesn't work in IE or FF. Works beautifully in Chrome

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox

Here's the code for the entire logout file. When I click on the logout link on my menu, it does nothing in FF or IE... Just refreshes the page.

```
<?php

  if (isset($_COOKIE['id'])) {

      setcookie('id', '', time() - 3600);
      setcookie('username', '', time() - 3600);
  }

  // Redirect to the home page
  $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/index.php';
  header('Location: ' . $home_url);
?>
```

Comment: is the logout page on the same path that the index page ? if not, add '/' to your setcookie.

Comment: Why not just use PHP sessions!?

Comment: i copied and pasted your code and it worked for me on FF - if you know the url that you want to send them to why not just put it as a static variable?

Comment: Not using sessions because required to use cookies for the school assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see where you really end up.

```
<?php

  if (isset($_COOKIE['id'])) {

      setcookie('id', 'bluefish', time() - 3600);
      setcookie('username', 'joe', time() - 3600);
      $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] 
                . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/cookie_was_set.php'; 

  } else {

      setcookie('id', 'deadfish', time() + 3600);
      setcookie('username', 'joe', time() + 3600);
      $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] 
                . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/index.php';

  }

  // Redirect to the home page
  header('Location: ' . $home_url);
?>
```

If you always land on index.php, it means the page tried to set the cookie but it did no work. So your browser is not letting you set a cookie. Other wise it would set the cookie time backward, and bounce you to the missing page.

Comment: But I do login though. All the same?

Comment: Loging in is not the same as setting a cookie. Maybe your login function sets a cookie, but it does not have to do that.